# Move apps automatically to SD card

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, external-sd, sd-card, application-manager

I have samsung A5, android 5.0.2, not rooted. it supports moving to SD card from application manager. Every time I update an app, it is moved to storage and i have to move it to sd card again.

Is there an app that move other apps to SD automatically after updates? I had link2sd and purchased the paid version long ago for a rooted s3 mini, but i don't find link2sd useful anymore. App2SD is just an interface for moving apps, it can't move apps automatically.

*If you want to know why I don't want to root, [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/how-to-root-samsung-galaxy-a5-t3170580), actually I want to root but there are no rooting safe rooting tools for my phone right now.*

Comment: Hi! Questions asking us app suggestion/recommendation are off-topic here. See [help/on-topic] to know more. However, [softwarerecs.se] is the fitting place for such questions, provided that you follow their [guidelines](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Firelord alright, flagged it for migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if this will help, but in Link2Sd there is a setting that can automaticaly move apps to the SD using the Native App2SD Method on android phones.
You can use this to automaticly move apps2sd nativly and have it show notifications when this is available. [image]

Comment: is your phone rooted? cause I can't select auto link

Comment: Yes, but try enabling USB debugging because most of the time LInk2SD needs this to be on to work.

Comment: I did that, still cant tick auto link apps from link2sd settings

Comment: I would say root your phone, but as stated above your unable to, so try looking on Google Play for an app that can do this.
One more thing Under install location did you select external?

Comment: if I click on install location it says `failure could not obtain root access`

Comment: I upvoted your answer because you tried to help and I'm thankful, can't accept it unless my issue is solved, I don't think link2sd is a solution, and didn't find any good app on playstore

Comment: Hope you'll fix this problem, for the moment you'll just have to do it manually.